List not scrolling completely when last item is an image in compose
I am building a chat feature and when opening the list of messages, the last message of the conversation is displayed at the bottom without any problem. But, when the last message is an image, it does not fully scroll and leaves half of the image hidden as shown on the images. I am using this method to get to the last index in the LazyColumn state property.
rememberLazyListState(initialFirstVisibleItemIndex = conversation.messages.lastIndex)
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(paddingValues)
    ) {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        Box(
            modifier = modifier.weight(1f),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {
           // LazyColumn with messages here
        }
        ConversationTextInput(
            modifier = modifier.imePadding(),
        )
    }

How it is now
how it should be

I think your list composable is Ocupid full screen and you are overlapping massager Edittext composable.
the first possible solution is to add a dummy space at the end of the list and the size of the dummy space is your massager Edittext.
second is do not overlap it. take a column and put both composable sides and give the .fillMaxWidth().weight(1f) this will work

The LazyList was already in a column with the TextField composable (See edited post with code snippet). With normal messages and the "Go to Bottom" button is works and are never hidden by the TextField. That is why I think that there is an issue with images and the list not being able to scroll to the bottom of the list for some reason when the conversation is opened for the first time.
